# How to disable buttons based on data model values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building a mini online shopping CMS project for collage.

I finished the project and now I want to add a feature where I have limited quantity of products.
When the quantity is equal to 0 then product is shown as 'out of stock' and my 'Add to cart' button becomes disabled.

I have added a 'quantity' property to my product class and now I need to change something in the *Index* view of the product.

I tried few options and it does not seem to work.
Here is the code for the *Index.cshtml* page.

```html
@model IEnumerable
<Product>
  @{ ViewData["Title"] = "Products"; }

  <h1 class="display-4 pb-5">All Products</h1>
  <div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="ajaxbg d-none">
          <img src="~/Images/ajax_loader.gif" />
          <p class="lead alert alert-success text-center d-none">
            The product has been added!
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="~/Media/Products/@item.Image" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        <h4>@item.Name</h4>
        <div>
          @Html.Raw(item.Description)
        </div>
        <p>
          @item.Price.ToString("C2")
        </p>
        <p>
          <a asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" id="addToCartButton" class="btn btn-primary addToCart">Add to cart</a>
        </p>
        @if (item.Quantity == 0) { }
      </div>
    } 
    
    @if (ViewBag.TotalPages > 1) {
      <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center">
        <pagination page-count="@ViewBag.TotalPages" page-target="/products" page-number="@ViewBag.PageNumber" page-range="ViewBag.PageRange"></pagination>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
  
  @section Scripts {
    <script>
      function DisableBtn() {
        document.getElementById("addToCartBUtton").disabled = true;
      }

      $(function() {
        $("a.addToCart").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let ajaxDiv = $(this).parent().parent().find("div.ajaxbg");
          ajaxDiv.removeClass("d-none");
          let id = $(this).data("id");
          
          $.get('/cart/add/' + id, {}, function(data) {
            $("div.smallcart").html(data);
            ajaxDiv.find("img").addClass("d-none");
            ajaxDiv.find("p").removeClass("d-none");
            setTimeout(() => {
              ajaxDiv.animate({
                opacity: 0
              }, function() {
                $(this).addClass("d-none").fadeTo(.1, 1);
                $(this).find("img").removeClass("d-none");
                $(this).find("p").addClass("d-none");
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  }
```

Comment: You need to place the logic to disable the button in the `@if (item.Quantity == 0) { }` block. Assuming you've tried that and it's not working, have you debugged what the actual value of `item.Quantity` is?

Comment: As per your code, you are showing multiple items in the loop and want to check if ```item.Quantity``` is 0 then disable <a>, So now here you can apply ```if and else``` and in case of true condition create <a> tag with controller and action else remove controller and action from their.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@If(Model!=null)
{
  @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {

..........

 <p>
 @if (item.Quantity == 0) { 
 <a disabled  class="btn btn-primary addToCart">Add to cart</a>
}
else
{
  <a asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" id="addToCartButton" class="btn btn-primary addToCart">Add to cart</a>
}
  </p>

}
}
```

Comment: I have tried that @serge and it does not work it throws this error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' For some reason it returns ProductID=0.

Comment: @student_code I am sorry but it is your problem. You had to post the model and the controller action code and ask why your model is null.